# Aligning div elements using CSS tables

Tags: html, css

All my `div` elements are generated in a loop so I am using css tables to display them.I found
a solution to display the images,but when I try add text with background to the images like in a featured post in wordpress,the whole thing gets distorted.I am trying to add the text to the lower half of the image.And,since it's a loop the `class` elements are generated similarly so I was trying to use `:nth-child()` function to access them all but it would not take.

my html

```
<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css"></head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="specialsticky">
     <img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" alt="first image">
   <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
   <div class="mast-screen1">
     <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a>
     </h1></div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>

  <div class="specialsticky">
    <img src="Chrysanthemum.jpg" alt="second image"> 
  <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
  <div class="mast-screen1">
     <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a>
     </h1></div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>

<div class="specialsticky">
   <img src="Desert.jpg" alt="third image">
   <div class="mast-screen" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
   <div class="mast-screen1">
     <h1 class="mast-header"><a href="#">This the title </a>
     </h1></div>
   <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
#wrapper {
display:table;
width:1024px;
font-size: 0; /* fix inline gap */
margin: 0 auto;
height:450px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1) {
display:table-cell;
border:1px solid #ffffff;
vertical-align:middle;
width:604px;
height:450px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(1) img {
width:604px;
height:450px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(2) img,div.specialsticky:nth-child(3) img {
width:424px;
height:222px;}

div.specialsticky:nth-child(2),div.specialsticky:nth-child(3){
border:4px solid #ffffff;}


.mast-screen:nth-child(1) {
height: 164px;
width: 599px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
background: #000000;}

.mast-screen1:nth-child(1){
height: 164px;
width: 599px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;}

.mast-header:nth-child(1){
visibility: visible;
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code here.. http://jsfiddle.net/nggrj1zt/

Comment: as you can see the black area is not in it's right position and in a browser it becomes worse,and the images get disproportionate as well.

Comment: There are additionals `</div>`s at the end of each `.specialsticky`, so the HTML page is not rendered correctly. I am not so sure if it makes the problem?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out,but the errors are still the same

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?